Requesting Information On Books
I believe books are the best substitute for having a coach, and it's the path I've chosen. Recently, I've completed Ilya Maizelis' The Soviet Chess Primer, which has left me with a solid foundation, although I had a slight concern that I may be a bit dated. I've come to Chess Stack Exchange to seek information on the best books about chess.
Artur Yusupov is a strong Russian GM, that was once third in the world, only behind Karpov and Kasparov. He has authored an award-winning chess curriculum of three series, distinguished by their covers. The first series which is the orange covers is recommended for 1500-1800 elo, which is about my current strength, so Yusupov's collection is an option that I'm considering.
Another author that I've heard of after much research is Mark Dvoretsky, who was also Yusupov's trainer, and unofficially 'The World's Greatest Chess Trainer'. Dvoretsky wrote 3 series, The School of Future Champions, The School of Chess Excellence, and his future works like his Endgame Manual. Though according to the internet, this may be advanced for my level but I'm willing to take on the challenge.
The final author that I wanted to mention is Jacob Aangaard, specifically his Grandmaster Preperation series.
I also believe in studying the 'Classics', which are the Laskers, Steinitzs, Capablancas, Nimzowitschs, Retis, and Tals books. I was also considering Garry Kasparov's My Great Predecessors, so let me know if I should get my hands on a few of these.
There are also plenty of other good books out there, and I've only scratched the surface. Please let me know what order I should tackle these books in, and if you have any other recommendations.

You should focus your question some and state the question more clearly. I believe you have a good question here at heart, it just needs tightened together some.

First Yusupov, then Dvoretsky and Aagard. If you find Yusupov to hard at first, insert a few tactics collections first.
